# what does this code block do in this program?

Tags: python

Code:

```
temp = inp = int(input())
count = 0 

while True: 
    ten = temp//10
    one = temp%10
    result = ten + one
    count += 1
    temp = int(str(temp%10)+ str(result%10))
    
    if (inp == temp):
        break
print(count)
```

I was wondering what `temp = int(str(temp%10) + str(result%10))`is doing in this code.

This code gets an input from the user, and gets the value of from tens and ones place, adds them, increment count and cycles them by adding the result and the number from the ones place until they become original input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line :

```
 temp = int(str(temp%10) + str(result%10))
```

First, you are calculating the modulo of temp and result by 10: this gives you 2 numbers. With the str command, you convert the number in string. With the + you are merging the two string one after the other. Then you convert your new string into an integer.

For example if temp = 10 and result = 50

temp % 10 = 1 --> in str '1'

result % 10 = 5 --> in str '5'

You merge the two str: '1'+'5' = '15' --> in int = 15

Comment: Thanks for the answer! now i understand how it works!

Answer (score 1):

That specific line:

- converts two integers into strings
- concatenates the strings
- converts the resulting string back to integer again

Let's say that the user input is 1.

1. `temp` would be equal to 1.
2. `temp % 10` would evaluate to 1.
3. `result` would be equal to (1 // 10) + (1 % 10) = 1.
4. `result % 10` would be 1.
5. If we convert the types of resulting integers from steps 3 and 4 into `str`, we can just concatenate them with `+`. The resulting string would be 11 (Because '1' + '1' is '11') An alternative approach to do that would be: `f'{temp % 10}{result % 10}'`
6. Now, passing the resulting string into `int()` would just convert it into an integer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! This helps a lot!! :)